# SharePoint 2016 and Office Online Server SSLOffloaded

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, office-online-server, wopi

We are having SharePoint 2016 (SP16) & Office Online Server (OOS) behind a reverse proxy (ARR) on-premises and offloaded SSL (ssl certificate installed on the reverse proxy only).

However, when users open files from SP16, there are 2 problems:

1. Warning: "Only secure content is displayed" > have to click "Show all content".
2. Subsequent requests sending from clients to oos.myexternal.com (proxy) are in both types HTTP & HTTPS instead of only HTTPS.

Please help to advise if anything wrong from the following details or additional configuration required on the proxy. Thanks.

**OOS**:
InternalURL                                  : http://oos.myinternal.com/
ExternalURL                                  : https://oos.myexternal.com/
AllowHTTP                                    : True
AllowOutboundHttp                            : False
SSLOffloaded                                 : True

**SP16 Binding**:
ServerName      : OOS.myinternal.COM
WopiZone        : external-http

*Notes: Understanding the offloading poses an insecure issue but mine's just a shared environment without any sensitive content, also the connections among the proxy & other servers are private. Just want to know configuration to make it work, pls don't discuss the security topic here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever offload SSL. This creates an insecure environment passing tokens that are as good as a username and password between SharePoint and OOS. These can be intercepted and replayed.

But you have a mismatch between your WOPI zone on SharePoint and your ExternalUrl on OOS.

Comment: Thank Trevor for your advice. I've just updated question regarding the security concern. I tried to bind wopi zone to external-https but it's not working also. Appreciate if you can advise what is the correct binding to make it work.